# wrap different className on component based on logic in react

Tags: reactjs, typescript, typescript2.0

how to provide different attribution on `div` to wrap a component based on logic?
I have one component as `button` in `Children` that need to be wrapped by a `div` with different element attribution based on logic. is there a better way or clean way for me to do it?

```
import "./styles.css";
interface HomeProps {
  showCase: boolean;
}

const Home = (props: HomeProps) => {
  const { showCase } = props;

  const Children = () => {
    const elementClasses = showCase
      ? { className: "showcase-y", title: "we have showcase" }
      : { className: "no-showcase" };
    return (
      <div {...elementClasses}>
        <button>button text</button>
      </div>
    );
  };
  return <Children />;
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <h1>
        <Home showCase={false} />
      </h1>
    </div>
  );
}
```